# GitHub - Do a pull request on a sub-directory

Tags: github, request, subdirectory, pull

I have a repo with a file structure like below:

Technology
.......HTML
..........Compliance
.......Java
..........Compliance
.......etc

Is there a way using GitShell to do a pull request of just Technology/HTML/Compliance without having to also update the java folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can not. You may create a new branch from the origin and commit all your intended changes. Then do a pull request from that branch.